# Is there an analytical solution here?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Can we solve analytically for $b$ in the equation below?

$$A = \int_0^b (b - x) f_{X}(x) \mathop{d x},$$

where $A \geq 0$, $f_{X}$ is the probability density function of $X$ and

$$X \sim \operatorname{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma^{2})$$

I strongly suspect that there is not an analytical solution. But I get as far as this:

\begin{align}
A
&= \int_0^b (b - x) f_{X}(x) \mathop{d x} \\
&= b F_{X}(b) - \int_0^b x f_{X}(x) \mathop{d x} \\
&= b \Phi\left(\frac{\ln b - \mu}{\sigma}\right) - \int_0^b x \frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(- \frac{\ln x - \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right) \mathop{d x} \\
&= b \Phi\left(\frac{\ln b - \mu}{\sigma}\right) - \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_0^b \exp\left(- \frac{\ln x - \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right) \mathop{d x} \\
&= b \Phi\left(\frac{\ln b - \mu}{\sigma}\right) - \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right) \int_0^b \exp\left(- \frac{\ln x}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right) \mathop{d x} \\
&= b \Phi\left(\frac{\ln b - \mu}{\sigma}\right) - \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right) \int_0^b x^{- 1 / (\sigma \sqrt{2})} \mathop{d x} \\
\end{align}